# Crawl multiple pages using Apify

Tags: javascript, apify

Is it possible to crawl multiple pages using Apify with Pseudo-URLs?

When people ask the same question, mostly the answer points to Pseudo-URLs and doesn't really address the question directly if it is possible / not possible to do this.

If I didn't know the Pseudo-URLs at the time of running the crawler, and I scraped say 10 links from a page — THEN wanted to scrape those 10 links, how would one do that?

https://kb.apify.com/tutorial-creating-your-first-crawler/crawling-multiple-pages

Comment: The link to knowledge base points to a tutorial for the Crawler product, which is now being deprecated. Please visit [the Apify SDK tutorial](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/guides/gettingstarted) for the most up to date information.

Answer (score 3):

### The short answer:

Yes.

### The long answer:

There are two main ways to add more pages to the crawling queue.

#### Pre-determined structure:

Pseudo URLs are used to follow links that conform to a certain structure. Websites typically use some structuring in the URLs they use. For example:

```
https://github.com
```

uses the structure:

```
https://github.com/{username}/{repository}
```

So if you wanted to scrape all the repositories for the user `apifytech`, you could use a Pseudo URL like this:

```
https://github.com/apifytech/[.+]
```

You can find more information on PseudoURLs in the [tutorial for Apify SDK](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/guides/gettingstarted#introduction-to-pseudo-urls).

#### Dynamically adding URLs at runtime

If you need to dynamically add more links to the crawling queue at runtime, there are several options.

When using [Apify SDK](https://sdk.apify.com), you can always make use of either the [`requestQueue.addRequest()`](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/requestqueue#requestqueueaddrequestrequest-options-code-queueoperationinfo-code-typedefs-queueoperationinfo) function or the [`utils.enqueueLinks()`](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/utils#utils.enqueueLinks) function.

When using the [Apify Web Scraper](https://apify.com/apify/web-scraper), you can add more pages dynamically using [`context.enqueueRequest()`](https://apify.com/apify/web-scraper#functions).

Comment: Thank you. When another page is enqueued based on a scraped URL, and that new page has new selectors (not the same as orig page) what is the recommended pattern? Do you pair up a new Crawler with a new queued URL? Is there any example on the Docs of that?

Comment: Sure, the [Apify Web Scraper tutorial](https://apify.com/docs/scraping/web-scraper-tutorial#crawling-the-website-with-pseudo-urls) explains this quite nicely. Basically, you need to do some flow control based on `request.userData` that the PseudoURL can populate.

[Apify SDK tutorial](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/guides/gettingstarted#finally-the-userdata-of-enqueuelinks) also uses this technique.